# QML: changing source of Video item causes hang

Tags: qt, video, qml

I have a trouble in changing Video item sources. In a code below I pick randomly a mov file from the folder on a mouse click. After 2 - 7 (max) times it always hangs (on changing). All movs are rather small (700 kb - 7 mb), H.264, Mac OS. Any ideas how to fix it?

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtMultimedia 5.4
import Qt.labs.folderlistmodel 2.1


Item {
    id:container
    property bool change_video: false
    width: 320
    height: 240

    FolderListModel {
           id: folderModel
           folder: "file:///Users/michaellevin/Dropbox/Movie/Xcanvas/XXX/animation/"
           nameFilters: ["*.mov"] }

    Video
    {   id: vvv
        width: container.width
        height: container.height
        //autoLoad: true
        autoPlay: true
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 0
        onStopped: play()
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: xxx
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*(folderModel.count))
            print(index)
            //vvv.stop()
            vvv.source = folderModel.get(index, "fileURL")
            //vvv.play()
        }
    }

    Timer {
        id: start; interval: 10; running: true; repeat: false;
        onTriggered: vvv.source = folderModel.get(2, "fileURL")
    }
}
```